# I want to get one wallpaper on two monitors streched, i have both of the monitors working fine. ubuntu 12.04

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to span single wallpaper over dual monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89417/how-to-span-single-wallpaper-over-dual-monitors)

im using ubuntu 12.04 and i havent found any information on my subject for 12.04 ubuntu please help thanks. Charles Jacobs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple application called nitrogen

```
sudo apt-get install nitrogen
```

give the path to your images folde when launching nitrogen

```
nitrogen /path-to-your-images-directory
```

Comment: it wont allow me to pick the picture that i have dowloaded from my recent downloads?

Comment: sure it will you have just to give the path of your download directory

Comment: (nitrogen:27656): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_list_store_set_value: assertion `VALID_ITER (iter, list_store)' failed
this is what comes up

Comment: (nitrogen:27656): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_unset: assertion `G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed
ERROR: Could not load file in bg set: Failed to open file '': No such file or directory

Comment: in which step you find this error? installation or launching?

Comment: i already have it launched it is when i go to prefrences and list then i add the place where to find it and click ok and apply and this is what comes up

Comment: (nitrogen:27656): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_list_store_set_value: assertion `VALID_ITER (iter, list_store)' failed
'/home/charles/Downloads/Dual_Screen_Wallpaper_Xp_3840x1024_52.jpg'

Comment: if you know of a wallpaper that works on this program and tell me where to find it ill attempt it that way.

Comment: http://maketecheasier.com/nitrogen-a-background-setter-for-lightweight-desktop-manager/2008/12/02

Comment: Be sure that the wallpaper size can fit the two monitors

Comment: yeah the wallpaper is big enough

Comment: At the bottom of nitrogen window , select automatic and Full screen as options. then try to restart and try as root. thats what i know for

Comment: when i start up nitrogen no pictures come up, the site that you set me to shows pictures immeditly after starting up?

Comment: try it i think so but i didn't try it before

Comment: alright the picture has showed up now and when i click it and apply nothing happens?

Comment: try to reboot or try as root or before restart lightdm `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: alright one sec

Comment: (nitrogen:29350): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: The connection is closed

Comment: sorry for all of the troubles tonight thanks for the help.