# Dual Monitor imaging

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm having an issue when I set the dual image to span. It seems to be centered with black around the image on both sides. I'm wondering how to get a full screen span to eliminate the black around the edges. Is there a way to do this with a configuration file?

Is it Possible to set an image to a certain monitor for a full screen span?

Comment: Are you trying to get your desktop background to cover the whole screen?

Comment: Yes :) Im trying to get it to cover the whole screen ive even edited the image in gimp

Answer (score 1):

If your monitors are different sizes, choosing zoom or fill in the background appearance settings will have the best results.

To have more control over desktop backgrounds for multiple monitors, try nitrogen ([see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89417/how-to-span-single-wallpaper-over-dual-monitors?rq=1)).

Comment: It doesnt work for me i tried nitrogen.

Comment: While I don't have any other solutions, sometimes when working with display settings, you have to log out and log back in for them to take effect.