# Span Wallpaper Fails When Monitors Different Sizes

Tags: desktop-background

When [using unity's own "span" or the nitrogen tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89417/how-to-span-single-wallpaper-over-dual-monitors/96979#96979) to get a wallpaper to spread across two monitors I get the following effect.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I tried using both a 4k and an 8k image and had the exact same result.

The resolution of my displays are 1920 x 1080 and 1024 x 768.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this on Windows 7, but my monitors both had a height of 900px, so that made it easier.

What you need to do is create a new image that's 2944 x 1080, and expand your picture to fill the entire canvas. Then set it as background using the "span" mode.

You hit the nail straight-on in your comment. The image needs to be the width of the two screens combined and the height of the largest screen.